# SVG Background-Image strange transition behavior on hover

Tags: css, svg, css-transitions

I have a button with an svg as a background. The `:hover` selector works fine but when I give it a transition, the button first gets smaller and then jumps back to the original size. How do I stop this behavior?

here's my code:

```css
a {
  width: 250px;
  display: block;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
  text-decoration: none
}
.prod-ueber .cta-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 310px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 45px;
  z-index: 5
}
.info-btn,
.korb-btn {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  float: left;
  transition: background .4s ease;
}
.info-btn {
  background-image: url(http://imgh.us/info-btn.svg);
}
.korb-btn {
  background-image: url(http://imgh.us/korb-btn.svg);
  margin-left: 12px;
}
.info-btn:hover,
.info-btn:active,
.info-btn:focus {
  background-image: url(http://imgh.us/info-btn_h.svg);
}
.korb-btn:hover,
.korb-btn:active,
.korb-btn:focus {
  background-image: url(http://imgh.us/korb-btn_h.svg);
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div class="prod-ueber">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/" height="290" width="426" alt="Minze" class="img-responsive">
    <h3 class="Artikelname">Malve</h3>
    <small>Description</small>
    <hr>
    <h5 class="preis">€ 1,79</h5>
    <div class="cta-wrapper">
      <a href="#" class="info-btn"></a>
      <a href="#" class="korb-btn"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- produkt -->
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, dawgs!

Comment: Possible duplication - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27760779/google-chrome-svg-background-transition-not-working-good

Comment: it seems that background image property doesn't work with transitions

Comment: kaiido yeah i forgot the -moz- vendor - sorrey!

Comment: Seems that's a bug on Chrome on the transitions implementation, background is not included in the transitions property. Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27760779/google-chrome-svg-background-transition-not-working-good

Comment: Alright got it :) Thank you guys!! Is there any workaround for this? I'd like to give the transition some smoothness - but i don't want to do it with border-radius (swapping the i- or basket-icon doesn't look good)

Comment: here is the workaround i have used `pseudo` element with `background-image`  http://jsfiddle.net/rk72xvdr/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a workaround by adding `background-image` for the `pseudo` element

```css
a {
  width: 250px;
  display: block;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .9);
  text-decoration: none
}
.prod-ueber .cta-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  left: 310px;
  width: 100px;
  top: 45px;
  z-index: 5
}
.info-btn,
.korb-btn {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.info-btn {
  background-image: url(http://imgh.us/info-btn.svg);
}
.korb-btn {
  background-image: url(http://imgh.us/korb-btn.svg);
  margin-left: 12px;
}
.info-btn:before,
.korb-btn:before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: .4s ease;
}
.info-btn:before {
  background-image: url(http://imgh.us/info-btn_h.svg);
}
.korb-btn:before {
  background-image: url(http://imgh.us/korb-btn_h.svg);
}
.info-btn:hover:before,
.info-btn:active:before,
.info-btn:focus:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
.korb-btn:hover:before,
.korb-btn:active:before,
.korb-btn:focus:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">
  <div class="prod-ueber">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/" height="290" width="426" alt="Minze" class="img-responsive">
    <h3 class="Artikelname">Malve</h3>
    <small>Description</small>
    <hr>
    <h5 class="preis">€ 1,79</h5>
    <div class="cta-wrapper">
      <a href="#" class="info-btn"></a>
      <a href="#" class="korb-btn"></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</a>
```

Comment: Thanks again!! 
This just works perfect - I know giving you the solution-mark isn't 100% right but in the end it helped solving my problem- so here are your points! Thank you mate

Answer (score 2):

Instead of setting the background of the image you can just set in the svg element itself. It might make you html a bit bigger but you can set the **<svg>** in a **[template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27954250/moving-to-svg-icons-how-to-separate-them-from-the-code/28029642#28029642).**

First lets just use a svg instead of background. (svg is xhtml so you can just paste it in html)

```css
#Ebene_1 circle {
  transition: fill .4s, stroke .4s;
}
#Ebene_1:hover circle {
  fill: #ffe;
}
#Ebene_1:hover path {
  fill: #b61910;
}
```

```html
<p>We can use the svg inside our html :D</p>
<svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="60.1px" height="60.1px" viewBox="0 0 60.1 60.1">
  <circle fill="#B61910" stroke="#B61910" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" cx="30.1" cy="30.1" r="29.3" />
  <path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M32.3,14c1.6,0,3.2,1.6,3.2,3.2S33.9,22,30.7,22c-1.6,0-3.2-1.6-3.2-3.2C29.2,15.6,30.7,14,32.3,14z
     M26,45.8c-1.6,0-3.2-1.6-1.6-6.4l1.6-7.9c0-1.6,0-1.6,0-1.6s-3.2,1.6-4.8,1.6v-1.6c4.8-3.2,9.5-4.8,11.1-4.8
    c1.6,0,1.6,1.6,1.6,4.8l-1.6,7.9c0,1.6,0,1.6,0,1.6s1.6,0,3.2-1.6l1.6,1.6C32.3,44.2,27.6,45.8,26,45.8z" />
  <rect x="8.2" y="14.2" fill="none" width="36.5" height="31.8" />
</svg>
<p>and it wil :hover. <br> Added some transitions to.</p>
```

Comment: Hey Persijn,
thank you for your anwers - i love it and you know first i thought about the inline-solution, too but just yesterday i had a mad discussion with the developer about inline-svg. He was crying about the bigger getting html-file and told me to embed an .svg-file... He's a hard person, you can't tell him anything else - he's a dick head haha but thanks again

Comment: @moesphemie its a valid reason to say that the html file gets to big, but hey maybe some one else finds this answer and does not mind the bigger html file.

Comment: Yeah i know what you mean, but do i achieve a better performance with inline-svg instead of embedding them?

Comment: I really don't know if there is better performance, but i do believe it save you a request on the server since its in the html and does not need to fetch it from anything external.

Answer (score 0):

If using a transition with a background-image the various background properties must also be explicitly declared
e.g.
{
  backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
  backgroundSize: '30px 30px',
  backgroundPosition: '0px 0px'
}